# Finding length of array from a Array

Tags: sql, arrays, google-bigquery

I have array field as give below in a column call emailed_user

[xyz@zar.com,eng@gmail.com,sahara@gamil.com,rashmi@google.com]

I want to find number of element in the array.

I have written the code for the above 
 ARRAY_LENGTH(SPLIT(emailed_users),",") as Number_of_items2

I am getting error No matching signature for function SPLIT for argument types: ARRAY. 
 Supported signatures: SPLIT(STRING, [STRING]); SPLIT(BYTES, BYTES)
 Could you please help me. Answer can be given in standardsql
 I am using Googlesql

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use below

```
ARRAY_LENGTH(emailed_users) as Number_of_items2
```

As you can see - you don't need SPLIT because your `emailed_users` field is already of type ARRAY

Quick test below

```
#standardSQL
WITH `project.dataset.table` AS (
  SELECT ['xyz@zar.com','eng@gmail.com','sahara@gamil.com','rashmi@google.com'] emailed_users
)
SELECT ARRAY_LENGTH(emailed_users) AS Number_of_items2  
FROM `project.dataset.table`
```

with result

```
Row Number_of_items2     
1   4
```